# Interactive web graphs

Tags: javascript, python

I have a collection of python scripts that generate some interactive matplotlib graphics that illustrate an economics model. Here's an example:

[image: econ model graphs]

I'm looking for a way to get these up so that they are web accessible. I've looked into creating an IPython notebook but I'm opposed to that idea because I'd rather not have people have to look through the code that generates them.

I have a basic knowledge of JavaScript and have considered rewriting them so that I could simply include them in a webpage, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Are there any tools to display a matplotlib frame in a webpage? Or is there some way that I haven't thought of to make this accessible via a webpage?

Comment: There are plenty of JS graphing libraries such as [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) and [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Comment: Do you just want static graphs, ot something people can interact with? What is your budget? What is your development stack? Please [edit] answers into your question.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking a look at the [Plotly](http://plot.ly) Python API - it should be easy to modify your code to give interactive graphs via that.